# Create Multiple List Items in SharePoint based on a Selection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a share point list called **Payroll Schedule** which contains a listing of our clients Payroll Schedule information. This list also contains the day and week (e.g. Monday Week A) in which we should be running these Payrolls.

I want to create a secondary list called P**ayroll Schedule Tasks**. Ideally I want our Payroll Team to be able to execute a workflow (e.g. Create Monday Week A Payroll Tasks) that then finds all the Payrolls in the Payroll Schedule that are marked Monday Week A and copy these to the **Payroll Schedule Task** list.

The idea here is that the user can then go through and mark each of the tasks as In Progress, Pending Client or Completed so we can correctly track the progress of each Payroll.

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Daniel

Comment: What tools/resources are available to you? (e.g. SharePoint Designer, 3rd party workflow tools, Visual Studio, JavaScript, server-side or client-side PowerShell, .NET) Also, what version of SharePoint are you working with?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have access to SharePoint Designer and we are running SharePoint 2013.